# Could not find a way to set the variables of a job or many jobs through script run in a before script attribute

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to display values from an .sh file into .gitlab-ci.yml but I cannot find a solution.
**PS:** I don't want to use environment variables in the .yml file

My versions.sh file is the following :

```
export PROJECT_VERSION = 2.1.25
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml is the following :

```
before_script:
  - ./versions.sh

my_build_job:
  - script:
    - 'echo "PROJECT_VERSION = $(PROJECT_VERSION)"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you don't want to use environment variables in the `.yml` file, but that version.sh script defines a variable.

To display it, the syntax would be:

```
- 'echo "PROJECT_VERSION = ${PROJECT_VERSION}"'
```

That is `${...}`, not `$(...)` which executes a command in a subshell.

But, as discussed in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 27921](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/27921), that will not work.

You would need to *source* your script, [as suggested here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/27921#note_181798824):

```
my_build_job:
  - script:
    - source ./versions.sh
    - 'echo "PROJECT_VERSION = $(PROJECT_VERSION)"'
```

Comment: @IbrahimMAATKI OK: I have found the issue discussing this, and I have included a workaround.